# wait vs wait up, fall vs. fall down

Tags: prepositions

Can you explain differences:

```
1a) Hadn't we better wait up for the slower ones? 
                     vs.
1b) Hadn't we better wait for the slower ones?


2a) The apple fell from the tree.
                     vs.
2a) The apple fell down from the tree.
```

Comment: thanks, bud due to lack of reputation i can't vote up your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
I believe the correct usage of *wait up* applies to the type of scenario where you don't lie *down* to sleep, but instead wait *up* for someone to come home. It has just moved into a more general usage to mean the same as *wait*.

`"Don't wait up for me, sweetie - I'll be working late tonight"`

2) 
An apple cannot fall *up* from a tree, so using *fell down* is a stylistic choice for a writer/speaker. There is no real difference between *fell from a tree* and *fell down from a tree*.

Comment: 1) Evidence from the OED: definition 7f of wait: to wait up: to defer going to bed in expectation of the arrival of some one.

Comment: But I doubt "wait up" was in opposition to lying down -- if we want to read anything into it beyond "English is silly with prepositions," I'd go with the interpretation of "up" meaning "awake".

Comment: @Ophiuroid Perhaps. I'm not convinced though - it seems to be the simplest explanation. I'm willing to be presuaded otherwise. ;)

Comment: thanks, bud due to lack of reputation i can't vote up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

While "wait up" has the "kid/spouse being out late" context of Chris Dwyer's answer, there's another one that appears in Baha's question.

The phrases "wait up," "slow up," and "hold up" are often used as an instruction to a person/group of people to stop/slow/wait for others.  I haven't heard it used quite as

> Hadn't we better wait up for the slower ones?

as in the original question, but have said

> Wait up!  We're missing Theresa.

many times.  (And yes, it's always Theresa.)

Comment: Agree, it's always Theresa. I took the exact sentence from the dictionary: http://lingvo.yandex.ru/wait%20up/